# Why is $f(1)=0$ on $f:(\mathbb{Q},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z},+)$, where $f$ is a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Why is $f(1)=0$ on $f:(\mathbb{Q},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z},+)$, where $f$ is a homomorphism?

My professor stated that $f(1)=0$ in the such case because:

$$f(1)=f\left(\frac{1}{n}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)=nf(1/n)$$

so we have $f(1)/n=f(1/n)$ as $f(\cdot) \in \mathbb{Z}$ he told that $f(1)=0$ but I see no reason why $f(1)=0$, why can't I just take $f(1)=kn$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$? If the neutral element from the first group was $1$ and $0$ for the second it would be easier to get.

Comment: $f(1)$ must be divisible by all non-zero natural numbers. The only such integer is $0$.

Comment: $f(1)$ cannot have a variable value, it has a fixed value.

Comment: Also note you can follow this up with that all integers are in the kernel of $f$

Comment: sorry why can't $f(1)$ depend from $n$? for example I can define $f(1)=a$

Comment: @DaviAmérico it has to be a homomorphism. How do you plan on defining $f(1/2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(1/n)\in \Bbb Z$, we have that $n\mid f(1)$. But $n$ was arbitrary. Hence $f(1)=0$.